# How to remove TimeZone in query to_timestamp Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm finding in Postgresql and I want to remove `+9` UTC value in my query.

**For example:** In to_timestamp column, I want to remove `+09`, and only keep `2016-02-26 00:23:44` value.

This is my query:

`select t,to_timestamp(v) from c1.hour where f = 22 and date_trunc('day',t - '1 hour'::INTERVAL) = '2016-02-26 00:00:00' order by t ;`

Here my result:
[image]

And this is my result when I didn't use to_timestamp:
[image]

Can I get some help on this please?

Comment: Start by providing your table definition - data types are essential to your question. And never post code as image.  We very much prefer *text* for that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) function to format `timestamp` to any desired string representation. Example:

```
SELECT to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

will return `2016-02-26 09:37:49` (without a timezone)

Your query have to be this:

```
SELECT t, to_char(to_timestamp(v), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM c1.hour 
WHERE 
   f = 22 
   AND date_trunc('day',t - '1 hour'::INTERVAL) = '2016-02-26 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY t ;
```

Answer (score 6):

Specify UTC:

```
select to_timestamp(0)::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC'
```

I am in timezone +08 and get the following result:

> 1970-01-01 00:00:00

With the time zone specification, I get:

> 1970-01-01 08:00:00+08

An advantage is you don't have to specify the date-time format, which can cause unexpected results for users. The system specified formatting is preserved.

Comment: I believe, OP wanted `1970-01-01 08:00:00` instead.

Comment: Yes, that's right. `at time zone "UTC"` will do that.

Comment: `at time zone "UTC"` subtracts 8 hours as well, that seems to be not what OP wants, but just to remove *+08* in your case while keeping the rest intact as if at your zone.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:
`cast("your column" as timestamp)`

Comment: Very useful approach. I ended up doing `trunc('minute', cast (col_timestand_with_tz as timestamp))`

Comment: that seems like a simple solutijon but not tested whether it is to simple and only looks right because i am either GMT or BST so +00 or +01 so difference would be minimal.
the answers that are more specific and specify 'at time zone "UTC"' seem more specific