# E TypeError: read_sql_query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Tags: python, pandas

Im using the function read_sql_query, i want to cast types when storing data in dataframe. I tried the rows below, but got this error

> E TypeError: read_sql_query() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'dtype'

```
dtypes = {
    'dat1': 'object',
    'dat2': 'object'
}
if function_1 =='f1':
    if (self.table_name == 'table1'):
        df_rows = pd.read_sql_query(sql=sql_query, con=conn, dtype=dtypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Documentation at [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) the dtype is new in version 1.3.0, so I assume, that you have an older version. Try updating it and try again.

Edit: For your requirement with the dates you could use the `parse_dates` argument. Just give a list of all the columns, that contain dates and Pandas will try to parse them accordingly.

Comment: thank you for yourr reponse ! unfortunalety i can't upgrade my pandas. The goal to set the dtypes when reading data from table, is that i have two timestamptz columns in my table, when creating the dataframe col1 was saved in object type and col2 in datetime64. My problem now is that the column saved in datetime64 was stored in, utc so not in the best datetime. If in source i col2='1971-01-01 00:00:00+00:00', in. my dataframe col2='1970-12-31 23:00:00+00:00'. Hope that im clear . Please tell me if you have some tricks . Danke

Comment: I updated my answer. You could use the parse_dates argument for this requirement.

Comment: I tried fmt = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S' df_rows = pd.read_sql_query(sql=sql_query, con=connection, parse_dates={'col1':fmt, 'col2':fmt}) and got this error **E ValueError: Array must be all same time zone**

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you would need to update your pandas module. If this is not an option you can always set the dtypes after you parse the database. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610592/how-to-set-dtypes-by-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Use the "parse_dates" argument for columns that are dates.

Comment: He is using read_sql_query, not read_sql and there exists the dtype argument in a new version.

Comment: Just noticed that. My mistake.

Comment: @BrianMuccioli thank you for yourr reponse ! unfortunalety i can't upgrade my pandas. The goal to set the dtypes when reading data from table, is that i have two timestamptz columns in my table, when creating the dataframe col1 was saved in object type and col2 in datetime64. My problem now is that the column saved in datetime64 was stored in, utc so not in the best datetime. If in source i col2='1971-01-01 00:00:00+00:00', in. my dataframe col2='1970-12-31 23:00:00+00:00'. Hope that im clear . Please tell me if you have some tricks . Danke

Comment: i got this error **E   ValueError: Array must be all same time zone**

Comment: fmt = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'                                                                              df_rows = pd.read_sql_query(sql=sql_query, con=connection, parse_dates={'col1':fmt,
                             'col2':fmt})

Comment: @Brian Muccioli do you see how to do please?

Comment: I think that you need to account for the hours ahead of UTC (values after plus sign). Check out the  %z option in the format declaration https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#:~:text=(5)-,%25z,-UTC%20offset%20in

Comment: Try this format fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

Comment: @BrianMuccioli it is still storing it in utc format :'( in source i col2='1971-01-01 00:00:00+00:00', in. my dataframe col2='1970-12-31 23:00:00+00:00'. (+1h)

Comment: To be clear, you are saying that in the database you have an entry "1971-01-01 00:00:00+00:00" and when you parse the database with pandas the resulting entry in the dataframe is '1970-12-31 23:00:00+00:00'?

Comment: Try using this in the call to read_sql_query parse_dates={'col2': {'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', 'utc':True}}

Comment: samething :'( @BrianMuccioli

Comment: it is 1970-12-31 23:00:00+00:00 (so doing the convert and storing in UTC) :/ how can i tell him take the value like it is.? Do you know @BrianMuccioli?

Comment: Can you expand on what the issue is. To be clear, you are saying that in the database you have an entry "1971-01-01 00:00:00+00:00" and when you parse the database with pandas the resulting entry in the dataframe is '1970-12-31 23:00:00+00:00'?

Comment: yess exactly. @BrianMuccioli because in the source timestamptz , (paris zone), and it stored in dataframe in UTC. I want to store the **1971-01-01 00:00:00+00:00**

Comment: You want to ignore the timestamptz encoded in your database? If so, maybe check out he to_char SQL function as used here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642192/how-to-remove-timezone-in-query-to-timestamp-postgresql

Comment: i tried 
SELECT CAST (DATE 'date1' AS timestamp) from table1; and got this errror E       psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type date: "date1"

Comment: What type of database are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?